# "Возможно доставка" или "Возможна доставка"?

Tags: грамматика

Как правильно пишеться "Возможно доставка" или "Возможна доставка"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: `пишетЬся` -> `пишеТСЯ`

Answer (score 3):

Корректно: Возможна доставка. В данном случае это прилагательное, которое согласуется с определяемым существительным.

Возможный-  Такой, который можно осуществить (обычно при наличии определенных условий, при благоприятных обстоятельствах). // Достижимый, доступный для кого-л.
2. Такой, который может произойти. // Наиболее вероятный, предполагаемый.

Возможно - нареч. к возможный, употр. при сравн. ст. Возможно скорее. Возможно лучшие условия. 2. вводное слово. Может быть (разг.). Возможно, меня не будет дома в это время.

См. Толковый словарь Ефремовой.